# Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 when trying to install matplotlib on Ubuntu with pip

Tags: ubuntu, matplotlib, pip

Was trying to install matplotlib on Ubuntu 14.04 with pip:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

But it says:

```
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/charlie/graphlab/build/matplotlib
Storing debug log for failure in /home/charlie/.pip/pip.log
```

How can I install it?

Comment: As the message says, you should see `/home/charlie/.pip/pip.log` for the details of what exactly went wrong.